# NGINX to allow headers with underscore

Tags: php, http, nginx, http-headers

I've setup an NGINX box with PHP-FPM. Everything works great, but my requests to that box send an extra request header, like: http_a_xpto (yes, it starts with "http_", and I cannot change it).

For some reason, all the headers with underscore ( _ ) are ignored and not able to be captured on PHP $_SERVER var.

I've enable "underscores_in_headers on;" at http directive, and even at server directive, on NGINX config file.

It's something missing in my config??

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to delete my answer because [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass_request_headers) indicates that `nginx` passes all request headers by default. Sorry for the diversion.

Comment: I have confirmed that `underscores_in_headers on;` in the `http` container is all you need to populate the SERVER var with request headers that contain underscores. Make sure you restarted `nginx`.

Answer (score 0):

Richard was right.

So, apparently it seems that only with "service nginx restart", that flag at HTTP directive, was loaded. For production environment, where you "normally" don't restart but reload, this might be an issue.

This is an output by experience since I did not find any information related with HTTP directive changes only work with restart. If anyone have a link explaining that, please share here.

Thanks!